# How do I get my webcam to work?

Tags: drivers, webcam, troubleshooting

since I started using ubuntu (9.04) I try to get my webcam working, but I never got any success, 2 years passed and I didn't get any progress, then, sometime ago I leave Windows out of my computer forever and now I can't use my webcam anyway.

I ask you: Is it time to try developing my own driver to my webcam? If yes, how I get started on it, I know a bit of writing plugins, extensions, themes, but I've never got my attention to drivers, so what do you recommend to me?

Additional information:

- lsusb

  - ????:eb1a Empia **Integrated** Webcam Elite Group.
- notebook - Asus A3H, Celeron M 380 1.6GHz 480Mb
- I have two other external webcams, they are recognized but their resolution isn't fully supported.
- I remember this lsusb because it was 2 years of tries, but if I try it now in the terminal it actually shows nothing, it stays like processing something and never show any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to write your own driver, i would suggest two things.

1) research the hardware of the webcam, including chipsets, ect. This info can be very hard to find in my experience of searching for it.

2) reverse engineer the official windows drivers. Im thinking debuggers, decompilers, etc. You need to know how the device communicates to the computer, and this information will be in here. Now obviously you wont be able to implement all that you see in there, given the differences in API of the two platforms, but it will give you an idea of any hardware quirks, and possibly why it doesn't work with standard Linux drivers.

Good luck, and i hope you succeed :)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get some hardware info and get the windows driver to it and start thinking in reverse engineering the driver. I'm getting some tips and tutorials about writting drivers under Linux, I hope I'll finally get some progress!

Comment: Good luck :) im sure there are many other users out there with the same problem for the same webcam.